# Is there a way to automate the addition of a toolbar to the Windows taskbar?

Tags: windows

The manual way is to right click the taskbar, choose "Add Toolbar...", new toolbar, and select a folder.

We've got the folder pushed down via Group Policy, but other than walking around to each machine I'm at a loss on how to add the toolbar to the taskbar.

Thanks.

Comment: Might be related: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/02/9388941.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the settings are stored within a registry hive which would be possible to export and then write a script to add to a user's registry. Have a look at [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/35377-45-toolbar-taskbar-script).